# how to manage sessions in django after the user is logged in (without using default admin )?

Tags: django, django-sessions

I build a forum in Django i want to manage user sessions when the user post something n check
comments on their own posts.
Also the particular user should get notifications regarding any activity on their posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django sessions are not tied to the admin. They are enabled by default. They are are provided by a middleware.

The `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware` middleware will populate `request.session` and `request.user` on any requests made to your app.

If the user is logged in `request.user` will be the corresponding  `User` object, otherwise it will be an `AnonymousUser` instance.

You can find more information in [the django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/?from=olddocs). This page includes the different configuration options, but you should be able to make do with the defaults.